# Bash AWK or IF statements

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ping

I am trying to make a script that checks a variable for a number then produce an output. I.e using ping and based on the tty, check if its running Linux or Windows. I might be over complicating things but this is what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$(ping $1 -c 1) | awk '{if("$var1"=="128") print "Host is LIVE Running: Windows OS"}'
```

Doesn't produce any output.
I have tried using IF statements without using awk it wont produce any output if I enter a IP that I know cannot be reached.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$(ping $1 -c 1)
if [[ "$var1" == *"128"* ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE Running: Windows OS"
elif [[ "$var1" == *"64"* ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE Running: Linux OS"
elif [[ "$var1" == *"Unreachable"* ]]; then
echo "Host appears DOWN!"
fi
```

Constructive criticism welcome!
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please edit your question and include how you are running this script. For more reliable OS detection, look into `nmap`.

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` if you want to use variable from environment you should set it. Like this:

```
var1=$(ping $1 -c 1) ; awk -v var2=$var1 '{if(var2 == 128)....
```

In `bash` when you compare numbers you should use:

```
if [[ "$var1" -eq *"128"* ]]; then...
```

`=` is for strings
in `bash` you can use both `=` and `==` and AFAIK they mean the same (in `if`)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the reasons why your scripts don't work:

1. the shell variable `$var1` does not exist inside of awk
2. even if it did, `"$var1"` in awk doesn't mean what you think it does - it's the literal text `$var1`, and without the quotes it would be indirectly specifying a field number with the value of variable `var1` (i.e. if var1 equalled 2, it would field 2 of the input, $2).  An un-initialised variable in awk has a numeric value of 0, so that would be $0 or the entire input line.
3. `$var1` in bash will contain the entire output of the `ping` command, not just the ttl value.
4. using the TTL value of an ICMP Echo Reply packet is an unreliable method of determining the OS of a remote host.  Windows isn't the only OS to use a TTL of 128 (and not all versions of Windows use 128, either).

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work, thanks for the support. This code just helps get a better view of what OS it could be at first glance.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$(ping $1 -c 1 -W 3 | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 6)
if [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=63" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Linux OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=64" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Linux OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=127" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Windows OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=128" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Windows OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=31" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Windows 95 OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=32" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: Windows 95 OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=255" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: MAC / OPENBSD / CISCO / SOLARIS OS"
elif [[ "$var1" -eq "ttl=254" ]]; then
echo "Host is LIVE! Most likely running: MAC / OPENBSD / CISCO / SOLARIS OS"
elif [[ "$var1" == "" ]]; then
echo "Host appears to be DOWN!"
fi
```